# Gunicorn runs by itself but not in docker container

Tags: python, docker, flask, gunicorn

I am trying to run Gunicorn inside a docker container here is my docker file

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine

RUN pip install gunicorn

COPY . /app

EXPOSE 8000


ENTRYPOINT ["gunicorn", "-c", "/app/etc/gunicorn.py", "backend:app"]
```

I've tried interchanging `backend:app` with `app:app` `app:backend` etc
but nothing works it always errors out and outputs

`Failed to find application object 'app' in 'app'`

After I build it I run:

`docker run -it -p 8000:8000 backend:latest bash`

Here is the folder structure from which I copy to `/app` to.

```
│   main.py
│   requirements.txt
│
├───backend
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   ├───cards
│   │      cards_views.py
│   │      __init__.py
│   │
│
└───etc
        gunicorn.py
        nginx.conf
```

If I run:

`gunicorn -c /backend-flask/etc/gunicorn.py backend:app`

Outside of the container it runs perfectly. So it must be something with my folder structure but I cant figure it out.

Comment: Try adding the following to your dockerfile as this is where you want to run your command from: `WORKDIR /app`

Comment: Have a look at [how ENTRYPOINT and RUN combine](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact).

Comment: The issue was that I did install from `requirements.txt` after I did that my gunicorn ran inside of the container

Comment: Have you tried launching docker with `--net=host` option? It looks like you're exposing a port but inside and outside container there are two different network interfaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding:

`pip install -r /app/requirements.txt`

to the Dockerimage file fixed the issue, that and using:

`docker run -it --entrypoint=sh [my container]`

the final dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine

RUN pip install gunicorn

COPY . /app

RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8000


ENTRYPOINT ["gunicorn", "-c", "/app/etc/gunicorn.py", "backend:app"]
```